# With PHP Deployer new code only shows up when recreating docker NGINX container

Tags: docker, cicd, php-deployer

my setup is as follows:
I have a CI/CD pipeline with tests running on one server and then with Gitea Actions (like Github's) I use [Deployer](https://deployer.org/) to push them to another server.

Now this works perfectly and the new code is actually in the current directory of the releases Deploer creates on the new server, but this doesn't reflect on the webpages themselves.

It still runs the old code that is probably cached in Docker because the new code only starts to be seen when I recreate the NGINX docker container.

Any help on how I can solve this?

Comment: If you put code into docker using `COPY` command, it will change when the container is recreated. I think you can try mount volume to container like `-v /app/current/:/app`